# Using web-gl or Opengl-ES 2.0 for Linux ubuntu

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I am having a linux ubuntu 10.10 version enabled PC and now as OpenGL is using shaders instead of fixed functionality. I want to know whats the best way to learn that . Am i choose OpenGL-es 2.0 or webgl or openGL 3.x or some other thing to learn it.

Whatever your suggestion please give me a reference to install and how to run codes on that .

P.S : I have done coding on OpenGL 1.0 through glut .

Comment: If you're on a desktop system, why bother with WebGL or ES? You don't need 3.x to use shaders and the like. You can use 2.0/2.1 in a "modern" style, too. By the way, I'm sure you have worked with GL 1.1 and not 1.0.

Comment: Actually I now want to use shaders instead of fixed function pipeline . now I am having a PC with ubuntu I want to know if I go with OpenGL-ES 2.0 or OpenGL 3.x because for OpenGL-ES 2.0 to run in PC we need Emulator so code Increases a lot big size.So to use shaders whats my first move if I am having a PC with Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a desptop, definitely OpenGL, without Web before or ES after.

You also don't need to worry if your system doesn't have a 3.x driver or you don't have 3.x hardware, as you can use shaders and all the like in OpenGL 2.0/2.1, too. So the answer is definitely OpenGL 3.x/2.x!

When you're working on a desktop and don't need to program embedded systems or websites, then there is just completely no reason to use WebGL or OpenGL ES, as these are just subsets of OpenGL 2.0 for specific purposes.

Answer (score 1):

What is your goal? The most general way to go is just learning the OpenGL 3.x API by using a language that has the API bindings. In my case that was C/C++. Make sure you get a recent driver for your video card, I'm not so sure about the OpenGL 3.x support of the open source drivers on Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually I now want to use shaders instead of fixed function pipeline . now I am having a PC with ubuntu I want to know if I go with OpenGL-ES 2.0 or OpenGL 3.x because for OpenGL-ES 2.0 to run in PC we need Emulator so code Increases a lot big size.So to use shaders whats my first move if I am having a PC with Ubuntu

Comment: I actually meant: what is your end goal? Using shaders is not an end goal, creating a specific type of application that should run on a certain platform is an end goal. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Okk I want to develop an application on Mobile but I want to use Ubuntu with c++ for programming practice not an Android platform with java so that later on i can switch to mobile when I am able to play with Opengl which can be used in mobile also.

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions on StackOverflow about "getting started with OpenGL". These lead to many materials you can use. Just ignore any suggestions that use the fixed function pipeline.

The OpenGL Wiki keeps links to a [number of tutorials](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides). That's a good place to start.

Comment: Actually I now want to use shaders instead of fixed function pipeline . now I am having a PC with ubuntu I want to know if I go with OpenGL-ES 2.0 or OpenGL 3.x because for OpenGL-ES 2.0 to run in PC we need Emulator so code Increases a lot big size.So to use shaders whats my first move if I am having a PC with Ubuntu

Comment: @Sudhanshu: The "ES" in OpenGL ES stands for "embedded systems". Your desktop PC is not an embedded system. So unless you have some specific need to develop for embedded systems, I would suggest following the link I provided and reading the materials you find there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn WebGL, then start at http://learningwebgl.com/.
And you may also want to visit [WebGL Dev List](http://groups.google.com/group/webgl-dev-list) at Google Groups.

And all you need is Chrome (preferred 11+) or Firefox (4+).